# Perimeter of the Unit Ball in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

**Exercise:** Calculate the perimeter of the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. show that $\mathcal H^{n-1}(S^{n-1})=n\omega_n$, where $\mathcal H^{n-1}$ is the Hausdorff measure of dimension $n-1$ and $\omega_n=\mathcal H^{n}(B^n)$.

I think I should use the **Gauss-Green Theorem**: $\int_E \nabla \phi(x)dx = \int_{\partial_E} \phi\nu_Ed\mathcal H^{n-1}$ for every $\phi \in C^1_c(\mathbb R^n)$, where $\nu_E$ is outer normal.

Comment: Isn't $\mathcal{H}^n(B^n)=1$ if $B^n$ is the $n$-dimensional unit ball?

Comment: as far as i know for example H2(B2)=\pi

Comment: What's your definiton of $\mathcal{H}^2$?

Comment: It seems that you are look for a recurrence relation, which should be related to this post: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Recurrences

Comment: Are you using  a scaling for the Hausdorff measure so that $\mathcal{H}^n$ is the $n$-dimension Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @Jack I guess so. Btw I think that with polar coordinates we find $d/dr(Vol(B^n_r))=Per(B^n_r)$ and thus $Per(B^n_1)=nVol(B^n_1)$.